# ¿Convertir las propiedades de un objeto en String JS?

Tags: javascript

Hola a todos tengo el siguiente array de objetos en sus propiedades valores entero estoy intentando transformar esos enteros a strings:

```
const pension = [{
  cat_bank_id: 91,
  cat_discount: 1,
  clabe: "901",
  curp: "ASDA",
  name: "asda",
  percentage: "12"
}]
```

Las keys que contienen el entero son cat_bank_id y cat_discount, ¿Como puedo lograr esto? de ante mano muchas gracias por sus respuestas y comentarios.

Estoy intenato de la siguiente manera, logro convertir el entero en string pero no se como generar un nuevo array de objeto con los valores transformados.

```js
const pension = [{
  cat_bank_id: 91,
  cat_discount: 1,
  clabe: "901",
  curp: "ASDA",
  name: "asda",
  percentage: "12"
}];

console.log(pension)

pension.forEach(pension => {
  console.log('sin transformar', typeof pension.cat_bank_id)
  const string = String(pension.cat_bank_id)
  console.log('transformado', typeof string)
})
```

Comment: Buenas noches, por favor, muestranos que es lo que intentaste, así podemos decirte donde está el error y como resolverlo. Literalmente solo debes igualar el objeto.propiedad al objeto.propiedad convertido a string, podrías usar un String(objeto.key) o un objeto.key.toString()..

Comment: Listo he actualizado mi pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una manera muy sencilla de hacerlo es mapear tu arreglo con [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), para aplicar la función toString sobre cada propiedad de tu objeto. Puedes acceder a las llaves de tu objeto con [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) e iterarlas con [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
const pension = [
  {cat_bank_id: 91,cat_discount: 1,clabe: "901",curp: "ASDA",name: "asda",percentage: "12"},
  {cat_bank_id: 92,cat_discount: 1,clabe: "902",curp: "ASDB",name: "asdb",percentage: "12"}
];

pension.map(x => {
  Object.keys(x).forEach(key => {
    x[key] = x[key].toString();
  });
  return x;
});

console.log(pension);
```

Si ya sabes exactamente cuáles son las llaves que quieres cambiar, no es necesario hacerlo sobre todas las llaves. Solamente deberías de considerar los conceptos de mantenibilidad de tu proyecto.

```js
const pension = [
  {cat_bank_id: 91,cat_discount: 1,clabe: "901",curp: "ASDA",name: "asda",percentage: "12"},
  {cat_bank_id: 92,cat_discount: 1,clabe: "902",curp: "ASDB",name: "asdb",percentage: "12"}
];

pension.map(x => {
  ['cat_bank_id', 'cat_discount'].forEach(key => {
    x[key] = x[key].toString();
  });
  return x;
});

console.log(pension);
```

Answer (score 0):

El tema es que el objeto lo puedes recorrer con for in en lugar de con forEach, esto basado en el primer ejemplo que pasaste, en caso de ser un array y dentro un objeto, solo deberías el array y su indice antes de el objeto, podrías hacer algo así si solo son esas 2 key para modificar:

```
const pension = {
    cat_bank_id: 91,
    cat_discount: 1,
    clabe: "901",
    curp: "ASDA",
    name: "asda",
    percentage: "12"
  }

  pension.cat_bank_id = String(pension.cat_bank_id)
  pension.cat_discount = pension.cat_discount.toString()

  console.log(pension)
```

O algo así si deseas modificar todas las que sean enteros:

```
const pension = {
    cat_bank_id: 91,
    cat_discount: 1,
    clabe: "901",
    curp: "ASDA",
    name: "asda",
    percentage: "12"
  }

  for (const key in pension) {
      if(typeof pension[key] === "number"){
          pension[key] = String(pension[key])
      }
  }

  console.log(pension)
```

Para pasar el valor a **string**, puedes usar tanto `valor.toString()` como `String(valor)`.

Answer (score 0):

así puedes convertir números enteros a string con la función `toString()`

```js
var obj = [
  {
    id: 451
  }
];

var NumberString = (obj[0].id).toString();

console.log("id: "+NumberString, "type: "+typeof NumberString);
```